# How do I store my CSRF token in my frontend nextjs headers. I store my jwt token in cookie

Tags: python, flask, next.js, flask-restful, flask-jwt-extended

I'm creating a website with flask and nextjs and authenticating with jwt and storing it in cookie. In my main page, I set my CSRFToken in my header in my nextjs (although I created a route in flask that sends CSRFToken and nextjs fetches it). It works on insomnia, but doesn't work on my browser. It keeps giving me a "missing cookie token" error. How do I fix it

In my nextjs, my headers is
`const res = await fetch('http: localhost:8080/api', { method: 'GET', headers: { 'X-CSRFTOKEN': fetch('http://localhost:8080/get-csrf-token')} })`
I was expecting to fetch json files in /API route